# jquery selectors in upgrading to html5

Tags: jquery, html

Quick question here...  i'm in the pre-process of html5'ing an old web app with some jquery on it.

there's some generic divs with actions attached that I want to replace with html elements.

For example, I'm looking to move my #masthead div into the html5  special selector. I suppose this also may be incorrect useage of header in the first place, though.   That aside, and i'll do more research on the actual set up, etc...   i have jquery on this id like:

```
$('#masthead').DOJQUERYSTUFFHERE
```

How do i put 'header' in there instead to continue the functionality?  Same as I would p or any other html4 element i suppose?

Since there is more than one, potentially, it may act as a class instead of ID.  So if i only want one, say ,

And what about the Roles?  Can I atach jquery to those specific id-like items to the spec?

I appreciate any guidance.  its hard to search for these things without knowing the actual terms to use.  any links are fine and appreciated!

Comment: The problem with you not knowing the actual terms is that it's very hard to get what you want. What do you mean with replacing divs with html elements ? Remove inline script ?

Comment: The only thing I'm able to get out your question is that you want to replace a `<div>` with a `<header>`, and I'm not 100% sure about that. I'm not clear why you need or want to remove the `masthead` ID from the element, however. I don't have any idea what "the html5 special selector" is. If you provide some short, concrete code examples, it might help clear things up.

Comment: Sorry for being un-clear.  I want to convert <div id="masthead"> to <header>.  And in doing so, I need to update my jquery selectors to match the change.   But, there may be multiple headers for each section and I only want to attach the event to 1 particular <header> element.  Therefore, role replaces ID to some extent.

I may just be compeltely wrong in all of this too.  That is certainly not for nothing.  Sorry for being vague.  I'm brand new to html5 and am still grasping all it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would *greatly* help if you'd post the relevant parts of your HTML code, so we know exactly what you mean. At any rate, you can select any kind of tag with jQuery. To select all `header` elements on your page, use `$('header')`.

But what if you have multiple `header` tags? Here's some HTML:

```
<header role="navigation">header with a role</header>
<header>this header has no role</header>
```

To select the first header, use `$('header[role=navigation]')` (there are other ways, but this is perhaps the simplest). Attributes are attributes. They can all be selected the same way. `role` isn't special; it's just a normal attribute, like `id` or `class` (or, say, `value` for an `<input>`).

Speaking practically, interacting with HTML5 elements isn't any different from previous versions. HTML5 specifies new tags and attributes (among other changes), but you won't have to learn any new jQuery tricks to select stuff. It's still HTML; it still works the same way.

That said, I would probably just use an `id` for this. Most of HTML5's new tags and attributes seem like more trouble than they're worth, with very little reward (not to mention they blur the lines between form and function). But of course it's up to you. If you have a good reason to use `role`, go for it.

Comment: Thanks, that will send me in the right direction.